# Visual studio is hanging on checking out items TFS 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I'm attempting to open a solution in a local workspace, and Visual Studio 2017 just hangs with this message in the lower left corner:

[image]

Here are my configurations:

[image]

[image]

**How do I get my solution to build?**

Comment: how big is the solution?

Comment: it's under 100 files, approx 6 projects

Comment: is there anything else in your workspace?

Comment: there are a couple hundred thousand files in the workspace, however the problem started when i opened this same solution from a different machine, using the same tfs credentials. does that make sense?

Comment: local workspaces do not work well with that many files.

Comment: so would the solution be to create more granular workspaces?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Have you resolved the issue by Tomhans's answer below? Any update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **not a good choice** to keep a couple hundred thousand files in TFS local workspace.

> ### When might I need to use a server workspace?
>
> When you use a server workspace, Visual Studio keeps only one copy of
>   each file. This can **significantly reduce disk space usage and
>   improve performance when you have a lot of items.** We recommend that
>   you use a server workspace if:
>
> - **Your workspace contains more than 100,000 items.**
> - You want to use Visual Studio 2010 or earlier versions to work with    the workspace.
> - You need to use the Enable get latest on check-out option.

The documentation is from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace). You should either use server workspace or create more granular local workspaces to work out this problem.